How to link C++ project statically to zstd.lib?
I have a VS2022 C++ project that uses zstd. Previously, it used zstd v1.5.2; I changed this to v1.5.6 (the current version). Now when I attempt to run the project, I get an error "The code execution cannot proceed because zstd.dll was not found".
So, apparently, the linker has assumed zstd should be used in a dynamic library, but I want to use it in a static library. I have the static library zstd.lib from the official release, and I want to force the linker to use it, rather than the dll.
I've created a small test project that illustrates the issue. Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#define ZSTD_STATIC_LINKING_ONLY
#undef ZSTD_DLL_EXPORT
#include "zstd.h"

int main()
{
    const char *pVn = ZSTD_versionString();
    std::cout << "zstd version is " << pVn << "\n";
    char src[] = { "This is some test data to be compressed, preferably by a large factor, using zstd in a static library" };
    char dst[1000];
    size_t compressedSize = ZSTD_compress(dst, 1000,
        src, strlen(src),
        ZSTD_CLEVEL_DEFAULT);
}

This project is being linked with linker options
General / Additional Library Directories C:\Miscellaneous_Libraries\zstd-dev\zstd-1.5.6;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)andInput / Additional Dependencies zstd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)The entire linker command line is
   /OUT:"C:\Miscellaneous_Libraries\zstd-dev\zstd-1.5.6\zstd_static\x64\Debug\zstd_static.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
   /PDB:"C:\Miscellaneous_Libraries\zstd-dev\zstd-1.5.6\zstd_static\x64\Debug\zstd_static.pdb"
   /DYNAMICBASE "zstd.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
         "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"
         "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL 
  /PGD:"C:\Miscellaneous_Libraries\zstd-dev\zstd-1.5.6\zstd_static\x64\Debug\zstd_static.pgd"
   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
     /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\zstd_static.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\zstd_static.iobj"
  /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\zstd_static.ilk" /NOLOGO
 /LIBPATH:"C:\Miscellaneous_Libraries\zstd-dev\zstd-1.5.6" /TLBID:1 

How can I prevent the linker from making the excutable attempt to load zstd.dll?
VS2022 17.6.5; C++20; windows 11 Pro 64-bit

Are you sure zstd.lib is the correct file? Just peeked inside the official release at https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases/download/v1.5.6/zstd-v1.5.6-win64.zip and there is no such file; there is libzstd_static.lib instead.

I think zstd.lib was built by vcpkg (the Windows package manager), but it is indeed a static library, per dumpbin. In any case, the error is "missing dll", so apparently the static library is being ignored.
